# Compare column names of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

How to compare column names of 2 different Pandas data frame. I want to compare train and test data frames where there are some columns missing in test Data frames??

Comment: To look at column names, use `df.columns`. Why would your test and train sets have different columns though?

Comment: You need to compare independent variables ?

Comment: A man has a question.

Comment: It's too big and after pd.get_dummies column count are not matching.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html) objects, including dataframe columns, have useful `set`-like methods, such as [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and [`difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html).

For example, given dataframes `train` and `test`:

```
train_cols = train.columns
test_cols = test.columns

common_cols = train_cols.intersection(test_cols)
train_not_test = train_cols.difference(test_cols)
```

Comment: Use the align method

Answer (score -1):

```
train_column = train.columns
test_column = test.columns

common_column = train_column.intersection(test_column)
train_not_in_test = train_column.difference(test_column)
```

Comment: Hi Nath. Please make more obvious the functional difference to the solution proposed in the highly upvoted answer by jpp. Explain what benedit your solution offers in comparisopn. Currently this gives an impression of being functionally identical to an upvoted answer with no explanation. Because of this impression it risks being downvoted.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.